# Mysql SUM 0 when not in another table

Tags: mysql, sum

I have 2 tables:

```
users:
id   |  name   |  club_id |
1       Bob         4
2       Jane        5
3       Alex        4 
4       Paul        4
5       Tom         4

points:
user_id    |   club_id    |   amount(can vary)
1                 4             10
1                 2             10
2                 5             10
3                 4             10
3                 4             10
4                 4             10
3                 2             10
3                 4             10

I need (where users.club_id = 4 AND points.club_id = 4):
user_id    |    name    |   sum(amount)
3             Alex           30
1             Bob            10
4             Paul           10
5             Tom             0
```

Notice Tom is present in users but doesn't have any entries in points, so his sum should be 0. This is what throws me off in conjuction with grabbing a list from users.

Also would like this to be as efficient as possible (hence I added club_id = 4 both in users and points)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  u.id,
  u.name,
  COALESCE(SUM(p.amount), 0) AS Totalpoints
FROM
(
  SELECT * 
  FROM users
  WHERE club_id = 4
) AS u
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT * 
  FROM points
  WHERE club_id = 4
) AS p ON p.user_id = u.id 
GROUP BY u.id, 
         u.name;
```

See it in action here:

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db1b2/3)

Answer (score 2):

try this query

```
select u.id, u.name, sum(if (p.amount is null, 0, p.amount)) as totalPoint
from 
user u 
left join 
(select * from point p where p.club_id = 4)p
on u.id = p.user_id
where u.club_id=4 
group by u.id
```

### **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/945324/5)**:

Comment: user `1 |  Bob ` should have total points = 10 not 20, because he has only one entry in the `points` table with `club_id` = 4 and points = 10 then it should be 10.

Comment: I assume this also works (didn't try) thank you for answering!